# Calling Function with type struct and returning pointer does not run

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I'm having trouble running the program, there are no warnings or errors popping up in CodeBlocks. The trouble comes when I create an ArrayList struct of pointer type and try to dynamically allocate memory using malloc. I'm using the syntax '->.' I've been at this for hours with no real leads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DEFAULT_INIT_LEN 10//this is in another header file

typedef struct ArrayList{//this is also in another header file
    char **array;
    int size;
    int capacity;
} ArrayList;

int main(void){
    ArrayList *test=createArrayList(12);
    printf("size: %d capacity: %d\n", test->size, test->capacity);
}

ArrayList *createArrayList(int length){
    int i=0;//index variables
    ArrayList *r;
    if (length>DEFAULT_INIT_LEN){
        r->array=malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1));//create memory for internal array
        r->capacity=length;
        r->size=0;
        for (i=0; i<length; i++)//sets members in the array to NULL
            r->array[i]=NULL;
        printf("Created new ArrayList of size %d\n", length);
    }
    else{
        r->array=malloc(sizeof(char)*(DEFAULT_INIT_LEN+1));//create memory for internal    array
        r->capacity=DEFAULT_INIT_LEN;
        r->size=0;
        for (i=0; i<DEFAULT_INIT_LEN; i++)//sets members in the array to NULL
            r->array[i]=NULL;
        printf("Created new ArrayList of size %d", DEFAULT_INIT_LEN);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList *
createArrayList(int length)
{
    ArrayList *r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
    if (r == NULL) return NULL;

    length = MAX(length, DEFAULT_INIT_LEN); // do not duplicate code. ever.

    r->array = calloc(length + 1, sizeof(r->array[0]));
    if (r->array == NULL) { free(r); return NULL; } // always check pointers

    r->size = 0;
    r->capacity = length;

    printf("Created new ArrayList of size %d\n", length);

    return r;
}
```

And you probably do not want to allocate `length + 1` elements, because you have `r->capacity`.

Comment: Btw, `sizeof(char)` in `malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1))` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I should have used this approach

Comment: @user3125367 It is not wrong, it is just useless, as it has the value `1` per definition.

Comment: @glglgl Compare size of array of length `length` and size of memory block allocated that way.

Answer (score 1):

you must first initialize Arraylist *r:

```
ArrayList *createArrayList(int length){
int i=0;//index variables
ArrayList *r=malloc(sizeof(ArrayList);
```

Comment: im not familiar with the new in c programming. i tried it and it dosn't work, maybe you're confused with java.

Comment: @abdolah: C does not have the `new` keyword. Therefore -1.

Comment: @abdolah: Happens ;) But you also do not cast the result of `malloc`. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).